# fullpage.js not working on mobile device

Tags: animation, fullpage.js

I use the plugin fullpage.js for a new project.
Now there is a problem. The Scrolling animation doesn't work on mobile devices. Here is the URL: www.manu-oliver.de/web/test.html

I hope somebody can help me. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `responsive: 900`, which means fullPage.js will stop auto scrolling in screens with less than 900 pixels width as pointed [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

> **responsive:** (default 0) A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used under the defined width in pixels. A class fp-responsive is added to the plugin's container in case the user wants to use it for his own responsive CSS. For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's width is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.

Comment: I am using background fixed image example of fullPage. I am facing the same problem where the effect is not reflecting in mobile devices. It works proper in chrome mobile emulator. Can you please help me where should I change the value of fp-responsive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added `responsive:300` in the options of fullPage. But still the background fixed effect is not shown in mobile devices. Please help. @Alvaro

Comment: @monisha probably nothing to do with fullpage.js. Search about the use of fixed backgrounds on mobile devices.

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you for the reply. Actually I was searching for a sliding effect similar to [link](http://silesoleil.com/etape/la-nuit) . Can you please suggest any plugins which works on mobile. Thanks in advance !